# Call jQuery to show a div in asp.net mvc5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a div tag in my HTML page which is decorated with alert class to show the alert if the login has failed. How can I show the div from asp.net mvc5 controller. I have made it hidden by writing the following script in my view(cshtml):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divAlert").hide();

    });
```

This is what I am trying in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.userDetails UD)
        {
            LoginApplicationEntity LE = new LoginApplicationEntity();
            userDetails udd = new userDetails();
            bool g = TryUpdateModel(UD);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (LE.user_details.Any(x => x.User_Name == UD.User_Name
                                        && x.User_Password == UD.User_Password))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("LoginSuccessful", new { userName = UD.User_Name });
                }
                else
                {

                    var script = "$('#divAlert').show();";
                    return JavaScript(script);


                }
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

This doesn't seem to be working at all. I have not done this before. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ViewBag to store a boolean flag. On the server side when your login script fails, instead of

```
var script = "$('#divAlert').show();";
return JavaScript(script);
```

save a true value to the ViewBag like so:

```
ViewBag.ShowAlert = true;
```

Then on the client side in your view you can add some logic using Razor to interpret the flag in the ViewBag. For example:

```
var showAlert = @ViewBag.ShowAlert;
if (showAlert) {
    $('#divAlert').show();
}
else {
    $('#divAlert').hide();
}
```